# Calculation of output power of USRP

Tags: power, sdr

I am using [USRP B210](http://www.ettus.com/content/files/kb/b200-b210_spec_sheet.pdf). ([product page](https://www.ettus.com/product/details/UB210-KIT))
I want to know the output transmitted power so that I could remain under FCC regulations.I am operating at a frequency of 2.4 GHz(ISM band of 2.4-2.4835GHz).

In the specification sheet it is written that output power is >10dBm and receive noise figure is <8dB.
How can I calculate the output power transmitted?Whether the output power given in the sheet is before the Antenna and i have to add antenna gain also??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a link to a data sheet and a guide to what you are talking about.
If you are using a $US1000+ device you'd usually try and know the sort of thing you are asking before playing with it. Deacronyming SDR may help. Or not.

FCC regs that apply are unknown as you have given no data on use etc.

Adding an external antenna may affect FCC acceptability deep ending on whether mrp or merp is relevant.

[Datasheet here](http://www.ettus.com/content/files/kb/b200-b210_spec_sheet.pdf)

0 dBm is 1 mW*.
10 dBm is 1 mW × 10<sup>(dBm stated/10)</sup> higher in power = 10 mW.

- *In audio and telephony, dBm is typically referenced relative to a 600 ohm impedance, while in radio frequency work dBm is typically referenced relative to a 50 ohm impedance.[Wikipedia - dBm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm)

> 10 dBm → 10 mW.
>   
>   Knowledge base.
>   http://www.ettus.com/kb/detail/usrp-b200-and-b210-faq

[Pretty pictures](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=usrp+b210&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=bl9bU9zWKo3ylAX8hIHwCw&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1032)

Related:

http://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/74.1235

[FCC regs: ERP, MERP, wow, yoiks ...](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=5KI8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA535&lpg=PA535&dq=merp+erp+antenna&source=bl&ots=sojKB4x4bc&sig=Sc5WAb6OBRoJWBi4zyKKtRCPrqs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c2FbU-2TM9aE8gXr04DQCA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=merp%20erp%20antenna&f=false)

[More yoiks](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=OJTjfNVuLwcC&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=merp+erp+antenna&source=bl&ots=0S6amPmgye&sig=9fB4EOUWdC5gSpt6OHnp7_GDK1I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c2FbU-2TM9aE8gXr04DQCA&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=merp%20erp%20antenna&f=false)

[Agh](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&%3C?SID%3E&rgn=div6&view=text&node=47:4.0.1.1.3.9&idno=47) & [More agh](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=587bd57075e10deae98b7b8a89470cb9;rgn=div5;view=text;node=47%3A4.0.1.1.3;idno=47;cc=ecfr)

---

- Overview
  The USRP B210 provides a fully integrated, single-board, Universal Software Radio Peripheral (USRP™) platform with continuous frequency coverage from 70 MHz – 6 GHz. Designed for low-cost experimentation, it combines a single chip direct-conversion transceiver providing up to 56MHz of real-time bandwidth, an open and reprogrammable Spartan6 FPGA, and fast SuperSpeed USB 3.0 connectivity with convenient bus-power. Full support for the USRP Hardware Driver™ (UHD) software allows you to immediately begin developing with GNU Radio, prototype your own GSM base station with OpenBTS, and seamless transition code from the USRP B210 to higher performance, industry-ready USRP platforms.

Comment: I will be operating in the ISM band of 2.4-2.4835.GHz..It can't be 10mW because it is very less for the USRP.Let's forget about FCC for a while...just tell me how to calculate output power for my USRP?I am sure that antenna adds no power as it is a passive device then 10mW is the output power?

Answer (score 1):

FCC limits for two classes exist ; commercial (A) and residential (B) as below:
Note the details of levels are in uV/m or dBuV/m,  not power in mW or dBm and  referenced to 10m distance using Quasi-Peak <1GHz and average >1GHz which converts dBm to dBuV.

To calculate your expected level, you need to know f, modulation type to get [quasi-peak](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/how-is-quasi-peak-calculated) or average, antenna gain e.g. 5-6dBi , cable loss, path loss at 10m.  So in theory you start with 10mW=10dBm then add all the factors 16 dBm at antenna and path loss is estimated below;

[image]

Read the Quasi-peak link above if applicable.

Finally the acceptance critieria

[image]

Comment: I will be operating in the ISM band of 2.4-2.4835.GHz..It can't be 10mW because it is very less for the USRP.Let's forget about FCC for a while...just tell me how to calculate output power for my USRP?I am sure that antenna adds no power as it is a passive device then 10mW is the output power?